# Relação entre várias tabelas no Eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel-eloquent, lumen

Estou tentando criar as models no Lumen com base no meu banco de dados atual para uma loja virtual, mas estou com dificuldades para configurar as relações entre elas.
Até o momento tenho as seguintes Models:

*Product

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

final class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'products';

    public function productColor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductColor', 'id_product');
    }

}
```

*ProductColor

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

final class ProductColor extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'product_colors';

    public function sizeByProductColor()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('SizeByProductColor', 'id_product_color');
    }

}
```

*SizeByProductColor

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

final class SizeByProductColor extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'sizes_by_product_color';

    public function size()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Size','id_size');
    }

    public function productColor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('productColor', 'id_product_color');
    }

}
```

*Size

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

final class Size extends Model
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'sizes';

    public function productColor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('SizeByProductColor');
    }
}
```

Meu problema é que nunca trabalhei com tantas relações e agora isto está me dando muita dor de cabeça.
Então, estou seguindo o caminho correto quanto as Models?
Obs.: Produtos tem Cores e cada cor de produto tem vários tamanhos de calçado e estoque. Exemplo:
Se eu precisasse pegar os tamanhos para determinada cor eu usaria o seguinte SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM sizes as s
LEFT JOIN product_colors as pc ON pc.id_color = 6 
INNER JOIN sizes_by_product_color as sbpc ON s.id = sbpc.id_size AND pc.id = sbpc.id_product_color
```

Como eu posso fazer Esta consulta no Controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no model produto

```
public function cores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Cormodel');
}

//produto->cores me retorna todo as cores do produto
```

no model cores

```
public function produto()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Produtomodel');
}

public function tamanhos()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Tamanhomodel');
}

//cor->tamanhos me retorna todos os tamanhos desse cor
//cores->produto me retorna o produto daquela cor
```

no model tamanho

```
    public function cor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Cormodel');
    }

    public function cores()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Cormodel');
    }

//tamanho->cor me retorna o tamanho daquela cor
//tamanho->cores retorna as cores desse tamanho
```

e por ai vai